# looping over javascript array of arrays with Data: for loop vs .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

My data seems to be an array of arrays I want to loop over it and use the data

If I debug:

console.log(alldata);

This is how the data looks

[image]

1. Why does it say  "Data"  ?
2. I cannot seem to get the data to display

This For Loop does not work

```
 for (var i = 0; i < alldata.length; i++) {
            console.log(alldata[0]);
 }
```

I would think that the length on that object would be "ok" ,  what am I doing wrong?

Also I have been trying a different type of loop with $.each and I'm not understanding the indexing

alldata,  index, query   ...
I know that query will contain the contain but I wish to loop over them .

It does not seem that I can do   query[index][0]  and I don't know why.

Here is where I attempt to loop and add to a variable

```
$.each(alldata, function (index, query) {
            //console.log(alldata);
            //console.log(index);
            //console.log(query);
            //console.log(query[0][0]);
            //console.log(index);
            strData += "<tr>";
            strData += "<td>" + query[0][0] + "</td>"; //+ query.outage_k + "</td>";
            strData += "</tr>";

        });
```

Update:

I added in another column from the database table to get returned and what I currently see is

```
122461,4876192
```

As now I have 2 records

So with that is shows

[image]

```
 $.each(alldata.Data, function (index, query) {
    strData += "<td>" + query + "</td>"; 
 }
```

That is spitting out 122461,4876192    how do I use "query" for separation?

I want to end up doing this

```
<td>122461</td><td>4876192</td>
```

Comment: That's an *object* with an array of arrays in it. You want to iterate over `alldata.Data`.

Comment: You will also want to use 'i' not '0' e.g. console.log(alldata[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an array of arrays. It's an object containing an array.

Here's 4 different ways to iterate through your array. All of them are functionally equivalent. Use whichever one you like the most.

```
// native JavaScript, ES6+
alldata.Data.forEach(x => console.log(x));

// native JavaScript, ES5+
alldata.Data.forEach(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});

// native JavaScript, all versions
for (var i=0; i<alldata.Data.length; i++) {
  console.log(alldata.Data[i]);
}

// jQuery
$.each(alldata.Data, function(i,x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: Nice, ok,  so this gives me the loop in which I see it spit out all those values, but now I want to be able to have more data so "x" would only be the first record, but what if i have a lot more data?

Comment: the function will be called once per element in the array. `x` is just a placeholder for the current iteration of the loop. The first time the loop runs, `x` will point to the first element (`alldata.Data[0]`). The second time the loop runs, `x` will point to the second element (`alldata.Data[1]`). And so on..

Comment: so for example this spits out   "122461" as it should  , but i'm confused on the function(x) as what about if the object containing a array with more data like in the image for example i have  0 :   122461 ,  but then if i had 1 : johnson   2: Denver    etc...  how would the loop work then to display it?

Comment: Post your actual data and the expected output in your question. Someone can help you better then.

Answer (score 1):

When you log `alldata` it is returning

```
>Object {Data: Array[9]}
```

which means that your `alldata` variable is pointing to a object that has a property called `Data` that has an array of nine elements. To access the array you would do

```
alldata.Data
```

Comment: I want to loop  alldata.Data.forEach(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});

Answer (score 1):

Your object has a property called "Data" so you'd have to refer to the array as `alldata.Data` and then loop through it that way.

EDIT: looks like @Austin is a faster typer!

Comment: I wish to loop over     alldata.Data.forEach(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});